# Insert dynamic parameters to sqlite database statements in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

in short what I want IS a way to Insert dynamic parameters to sqlite database statements  to make my class dynamic ... you may ask **Dynamic how ??**
okay I will answer you let's assume that I have this table inside my db

```
CREATE TABLE "Users" (
`id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`username`  TEXT,
`password`  TEXT )
```

and I have this class named **MySqlHandler** to handle all sqlite related operations like Selection, Insertion .. and so on and so forth.

inside our class I have fetch_rows_as_array which  i want to make it dynamic in order to handle all the insert command

```
public class MySQl {

    Connection conn;
    public PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    // get connected with the database it only called from LoginController 
    public void Connect(){

        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            // Get a live Connection to the database
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");

            System.out.println("connected with success!");

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }

    // this method will handle any kind of selection from our database
    public void fetch_rows_as_array(String query){

        try{
            // create  a statement
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            // Execute Query and return arrays of results
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next())
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + rs.getString(2));

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

// please note the code above in not totally correct its just for explanation

now the method fetch_rows_as_array can act just fine but let's say that in one case i want to get all the columns ... and in an other case i want from the same method to get all the  columns where username = someValue .. and in the last case i want to  get all the column where the username = somevalue and the password = ?, but its really important for me to make the same function do all of the three cases..

in order for me to achieve this .. I thought i should try something like this (from another class)

```
MySQl sql = new MySQl();
        sql.Connect();

        try {
            sql.prstmt.setString(1, "admin");
            sql.prstmt.setString(2, "123");

            sql.fetch_rows_as_array("select username,password from Users where username=? and password=?");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and it turned out that my code was wrong ...

> in short I want a way to add parameters to the statement from outside the class .. in another words I want to Insert dynamic parameters to sqlite database statements

I hope you got my point .

Comment: No my question is not duplicate at all if so please give me the direct answer .. .??

Comment: You are using `executeQuery(String)` which is not supported on a prepared statement; you need to call `executeQuery()` (without a parameter!) as answered in the accepted answer of the linked question. If you want to know how to use a prepared statement with parameters, you might want to consider following the [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).